# Condition in Material UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do you put a conditional styles in Material UI in React?

```
<div className={clsx(selectedCount > 0 classes.red : classes.table)} >
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with lambda expression? maybe something like this `className={selectedCount > 0 ? clsx(classes.red) : clsx(classes.table)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `?`

```
className={selectedCount > 0 ? classes.red : classes.table}
```